# Windows 7 can't see wireless printer

Tags: windows, printer

I have a P1102W printer from HP.  I have a Windows 7 machine.  I have a MacBook Pro.  I setup the printer following the instructions from the Windows 7 machine.  I am able to print from the Mac but not the Windows 7 machine.  And to add, I am not able to print from any Windows 7 machines.  The MacBook Pro address is 198.168.2.115, the Windows machine is 192.168.2.117, and the printer in 192.168.2.140.

I can ping the printer from the Mac.  I can ping the Windows 7 machine from the mac.  I can ping the mac from the windows 7 machine.  When I try to ping the printer from the Windows 7 machine I get destination unreachable.    I can browse to the printer IP address from the mac and not the Windows 7.  I have turned off the firewall on the Windows 7 machine and turned on network sharing.  Is there something else I am missing.  I can connect the printer with a USB cable to the Windows machine and print.  I can not get the Windows machine to see the printer even though they are on the same network.

Comment: Can you post `ipconfig` output from the Windows machine and `ifconfig` from the Mac? What SNM is the printer using? A traceroute from the Windows machine to the printer wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Might you have some other security software active preventing you from contacting the printer?  You might also want to see if you can access it from a Linux distribution's live CD.

Comment: I am experiencing the same symptoms, if you were to replace "Mac" with "Linux". No firewall. No antivirus. Can ping Linux from Win7, Win7 from Linux, printer from Linux but not printer from Win7. tracert from Win7 to printer reports destination host unreachable on first hop. traceroute from Linux reports  3002.139 ms !H  3002.134 ms !H  3002.125 ms !H on first hop.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is not properly answered, one normal solution (and worked every time in my case) it's to DISABLE other network adapters in Windows 7.

The symptom is that ping TO other computers works, FROM other computers WORKS, but when printer is pinged, Destination Unreachable from the windows 7 computer IP address is shown on CMD.

Just disable any other adapter on the computer (leave only the wifi on) and that will do !

(related to: [Pinging a machine on my local network gets an 'unreachable' response from my own IP address?](https://superuser.com/questions/453933/pinging-a-machine-on-my-local-network-gets-an-unreachable-response-from-my-own) )

Answer (score 1):

I had pretty much the same problem with a Brother MFC-665CW printer.

I have just assigned a static IP address to my printer and I can now ping it and print to it from my Windows 7 PC.

UPDATE: A few hours later I couldn't ping the printer again. I reset my wireless router to factory defaults and I can ping it again.

I suspect the problem is not with Windows 7 but rather the router.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run sfc /scannow at a Admin Command Prompt. Doing so will inspect all the important windows files including the DLL if it fines a issue with any file it will replace the corrupt files. I have fixed printer problems with this command many times.

Good Luck.